# How to make FindRoot work with PolyLog functions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following code:

```
q = 1.6*10^-19;
hbar := 6.63/(2*\[Pi])*10^-34;
m0 = 9.1*10^-31;
kb = 1.38*10^-23;
Cap := 4.5*10^-3;
W := 50*10^-6;
mu := 4.3*10^-4;
n := 20;
vth = ((3*kb*300)/m0)^0.5;
vt := -3.5;
Rex := 15 ;
vg = 0;
Plot[id /. 
  FindRoot[(id - (Cap*W*mu*(n*vth)^2)/(
      7*10^-6)*(PolyLog[2, -Exp[(vd - id - vg + vt)/(n*vth)]] - 
        PolyLog[2, Exp[(id - vg + vt)/(n*vth)]])), {id, 
    10^-6}], {vd, -1, .872}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AxesLabel -> {vd, id}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

It shows this error:

[image]

How can I specify the correct AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal for my problem. Also I want to plot the $id$ as a function of $vd$ for different $vg$, is there a way to automate it?

Comment: For your first question, you can look them up in the docs for `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with some or all of these changes [*update*: changed starting points to complex numbers `±10^6(1±I)`]:

```
ReImPlot[                        (* solution is complex-valued *)
 id /. FindRoot[(id - (Cap*W*mu*(n*vth)^2)/(7*10^-6)*(PolyLog[
         2, -Exp[(vd - id - vg + vt)/(n*vth)]] - 
        PolyLog[2, Exp[(id - vg + vt)/(n*vth)]])),
   {id, Sign[vd] 10^6 + 10^6 I}  (* better starting point *)
   ],
 {vd, -10^8, 10^8},              (* larger plot domain *)
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {vd, id}, 
 LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Changing the starting point to `Sign[vd] 10^6 - 10^6 I` gives conjugate solutions.

Comment: If I just want the solution from {vd,-10,0}, how do I decide what estimate of id I should give? Is there some way to estimate that or automate that? When I try plotting the solution for  {vd,-10,0} I get the same error I showed in my original question.

Comment: Thanks, it clears a lot of confusion. Do you have any recommendations on how to solve it for different vg as in for vg={0,1,2,3,4,5,6} and plot id-vd?

Comment: @Indeterminate  From `PolyLog[2, Exp[(id - vg + vt)/(n*vth)]]`, it follows that no real solution exists for  `id - vg + vt > 0`.

Comment: @Indeterminate Turns out `FindRoot` wasn't looking for complex solutions for small negative `vd`. Add an imaginary part to the starting point to force that. Then there are conjugate solutions for `vd` above around `-1.4 * 10^7` judging from the graph.